# Expose same Azure webapp with 2 URLs one within corporate network only and one public

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network

We have a web app deployed in azure. We want to have 2 URLs for the same webapp(example www.abc.com, www.pqr.com) internally pointing to single hosted web app.
Is it possible that we can restirct www.abc.com within corporate network but www.pqr.com available over public internet?
We want anyone who access webapp using www.abc.com must be connected using company's coroporate network. and www.pqr.com should be accessible on internet anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Application Gateway infront of your Web App to achieve your ask.

Create 2 FrontendIPs one with Private IP for Corp-net connectivity and another for Public communication.

You need to point www.abc.com to Application Gateway Private IP in your On-Premises. You can use one HTTP settings and rewrite the hostname to your Web App FQDN.

You can follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/create-web-app) documentation.